# Filtrar lista con fecha

Tags: vba, ms-access

En un formulario, tengo una lista (*lstProyectos*) en la que aparecen unos cuantos proyectos, junto con un campo de fecha (*txtFecha*) y otro de un intervalo de fechas *(FechaDesde* y *FechaHasta*).

Lo que se pretende conseguir es hacer un filtro conjunto en el que, si se seleccionan x proyectos en tal fecha, solo aparezcan los proyectos que se hicieron en esa fecha o intervalo de fechas.

La lista sola se filtra bien, pero no consigo hacer que filtre también la fecha.

Este es el código que he intentado, fijándome de otro filtro total que tengo, pero no ha funcionado...

```
Private Sub cmdOpenQuery_Click()

    Const cstrQuery As String = "Filtro"
    Dim strNames As String
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim varItm As Variant
    Dim FiltroFecha As String
    Dim FiltroFechaU As String
    Dim FiltroTotal As String

    strSelect = "SELECT QryTrabajadores.PROYECTO, QryTrabajadores.Trabajador, QryTrabajadores.FECHA, QryTrabajadores.TIEMPO" & vbCrLf & "FROM QryTrabajadores"

    For Each varItm In Me.lstProyecto.ItemsSelected
        strNames = strNames & ",'" & _
            Me.lstProyecto.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
    Next varItm
    
    If Len(strNames) > 0 Then
        strNames = Mid(strNames, 2)
        strSelect = strSelect & vbCrLf & _
            "WHERE QryTrabajadores.PROYECTO IN (" & strNames & ")"
    End If
    
    If IsNull(Me.FechaDesde) And IsNull(Me.FechaHasta) Then
        FiltroFecha = ""
    Else
        FiltroFecha = "FECHA BETWEEN #" & Format(Nz(Me.FechaDesde, #1/1/2020#), "mm/dd/yyyy") & _
                    "# AND #" & Format(Nz(Me.FechaHasta, #12/31/2050#), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
    End If
    
    If IsNull(Me.txtFecha) And IsNull(Me.txtFecha) Then
        FiltroFechaU = ""
    Else
        FiltroFechaU = "FECHA BETWEEN #" & Format(Nz(Me.txtFecha, #1/1/2020#), "mm/dd/yyyy") & _
                    "# AND #" & Format(Nz(Me.txtFecha, #12/31/2050#), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
    End If
    
    If FiltroFecha <> "" Then
        If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
            FiltroTotal = FiltroTotal & " AND " & FiltroFecha
        Else
            FiltroTotal = FiltroFecha
        End If
    End If
    
    If FiltroFechaU <> "" Then
        If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
            FiltroTotal = FiltroTotal & " AND " & FiltroFechaU
        Else
            FiltroTotal = FiltroFechaU
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print FiltroTotal
    
    If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
        Me.Subformulario.Form.Filter = FiltroTotal
        Me.Subformulario.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Subformulario.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If
                
    Debug.Print strSelect
    
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(cstrQuery).SQL = strSelect
    
    DoCmd.OpenReport "IFiltro", acViewPreview, cstrQuery
    
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que no funciona? El resultado de `Debug.Print strSelect` cual es?

Comment: Al pulsar el botón, se imprime el informe con los proyectos seleccionados, pero ignora la fecha

Comment: No recuerdo bien en Access, pero me suena muy mal ver cosas como `Me.FechaDesde`, creo que debería ser `Me.FechaDesde.Value` y así con el resto de referencias a controles como `Me.txtFecha`, etc.

Comment: El código intenté fusionarlo de otro filtro total, es decir, el otro filtro total que tengo funciona perfectamente y de ahí es la parte de `If IsNull(Me.FechaDesde)...` Entonces se supone que tendría que funcionar igual, ¿no?

Comment: En teoría la referencia `Me.FechaDesde` es una referencia a un objeto, para hacer referencia al su valor debería se `Me.FechaDesde.Value`. De todas formas antes del `If IsNull(Me.FechaDesde) And IsNull(Me.FechaHasta) Then` pon una linea con `Debug.Print Me.FechaDesde` y otra con `Debug.Print Me.FechaDesde.Value`, a ver que valores aparecen en el debug.

Comment: Si busco solo por fecha, me filtra bien. Y si busco solo por proyecto también. El problema es que si pongo ambos filtros, le da preferencia al proyecto ignorando la fecha. Puse ese código,pero realmente no aprecié ningún cambio.

Comment: No logro entender cuál es el problema. Sugiero que aísles el código, dado que tienes demasiados `if ... then else ...`, prueba un código únicamente con lo que dices que no funciona, quizá el problema esté en el flujo, al tener tantos condicionales puede haber algo mal en otra parte. Quizá haya que pensar en optimizar un poco, evitando tantos `if`, pero esa sería otra etapa, una vez determines dónde está el problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de aislar el código e ir probando combinaciones, logré dar con el resultado que quería.

Con este código ahora si selecciono uno o varios proyectos en un intervalo de fechas, salta el informe con los datos filtrados correspondientes.

```
Private Sub cmdOpenQuery_Click()

    Const cstrQuery As String = "Filtro"
    Dim strNames As String
    Dim strSelect As String
    Dim varItm As Variant
    Dim FiltroFecha As String
    Dim FiltroTotal As String

    strSelect = "SELECT QryTrabajadores.PROYECTO, QryTrabajadores.Trabajador, QryTrabajadores.FECHA, QryTrabajadores.TIEMPO" & vbCrLf & "FROM QryTrabajadores"

    For Each varItm In Me.lstProyecto.ItemsSelected
        strNames = strNames & ",'" & _
            Me.lstProyecto.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
    Next varItm
    
    If Len(strNames) > 0 Then
        strNames = Mid(strNames, 2)
        strSelect = strSelect & vbCrLf & _
            "WHERE QryTrabajadores.PROYECTO IN (" & strNames & ")"
    End If
    
    If IsNull(Me.FechaDesde) And IsNull(Me.FechaHasta) Then
        FiltroFecha = ""
    Else
        FiltroFecha = "FECHA BETWEEN #" & Format(Nz(Me.FechaDesde, #1/1/2020#), "mm/dd/yyyy") & _
                    "# AND #" & Format(Nz(Me.FechaHasta, #12/31/2050#), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
    End If
    
    If FiltroFecha <> "" Then
        If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
            FiltroTotal = FiltroTotal & " AND " & FiltroFecha
        Else
            FiltroTotal = FiltroFecha
        End If
    End If
    
    If FiltroTotal <> "" Then
        Me.Subformulario.Form.Filter = FiltroTotal
        Me.Subformulario.Form.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Subformulario.Form.FilterOn = False
    End If
                
    Debug.Print strSelect
        
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(cstrQuery).SQL = strSelect
    DoCmd.OpenReport "IFiltro", acViewPreview, cstrQuery, FiltroTotal
    
End Sub
```